# Delphi tethering PairedManagers out of range

Tags: delphi, delphi-10.2-tokyo, tethering

Delphi 10.2.3

```
procedure TMainForm.FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
var i: Integer;

begin
  try

    CodeSite.Send('In FormDestroy, MyTetheringAppProfile.Disconnect() has ' + IntToStr(MyTetheringManager.RemoteProfiles.Count) + ' profiles.');

    for i:= MyTetheringManager.PairedManagers.Count-1 downto 0 do
      MyTetheringManager.UnPairManager(MyTetheringManager.PairedManagers[i]);
```

UnPairManager() throws a range exception error.

I don't see how that is possible as there is only one manager. 
i=0 and MyTetheringManager.PairedManagers.Count=1 when tracing into the code.

How is it possible for this to be out of range?

Comment: Please provide the callstack; an out of range exception could happen in a number of places inside that routine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once I connected both apps to same Codesite, I could see that the "server" side of the tethering was disconnecting during the client's FormDestroy code.